# Animate supposed to modify clicked li width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a list of li, and when one of them is clicked, animations are triggered. Nevertheless, my last animate does not work. It is supposed to modify the size of the clicked li: `$('#wrapper li').index(this).css({'width': '200px'});`
Do note that if I remove "`.index(this)`" it is working on all li, but again this is not what I want. Here below the full code. Thank you very much in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
$('#wrapper li').click(function () {

    //Here is set my varaibles

     $('#wrapper li').slice(startLi, endLi).animate({
         "left": '-=' + leftDistance
     }, "fast", function () {
         $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
             "left": "+=225px"
         }, "slow", function () {
             $('#wrapper li').index(this).css({'width': '200px'});
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) returns a `Number`, which is why [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) is not working.

> It is supposed to modify the size of the clicked li

You could make it work by caching the outer value of `this` (which inside the event handler refers to the clicked element) and using it in your animate function later:

```
$('#wrapper li').click(function () {
    var self = this;
    //Here is set my varaibles

     $('#wrapper li').slice(startLi, endLi).animate({
         "left": '-=' + leftDistance
     }, "fast", function () {
         $('#wrapper li').slice(indexLi + 1, endLi).stop().animate({
             "left": "+=225px"
         }, "slow", function () {
             $(self).css({'width': '200px'});
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Hy Andrew. It is working! Thank you very much. You rock! You made my evening starting nicely.